# Mini Ripple Effect puzzles

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

I enjoyed [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47718/question-16-ripple-effect) so much that I created some mini versions of it for fun. I signed up to share them with everyone. The rules are the same: Each region with n cells contains all the numbers from 1 to n and if two cells with the same number k are on the same row or column then there are at least k cells between them.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Glad you liked my puzzle c:

Comment: Thanks! And I hope that you'll enjoy these simpler ones :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer:

> [image: Ripples]

1:

> Order of solving: light blue, light green, orange, red, pink
>  [image: Ripple 1]

2:

> Order of solving: light blue, light green, orange, red, pink, dark blue, purple, brown, black, grey, yellow, dark green
>  [image: Ripple 2]

3.

> Order of solving: light blue, light green, orange, red, pink, dark blue, purple, brown
>  [image: Ripple 3]
>  Green 2: the 2 in the top-right region must be in the right column. Then the 2 in the bottom-right region must be in the bottom row. Then the 2 in the + region must be in the centre.
>  Green 3: the only number that can go there.

4:

> Order of solving: light blue, light green, orange, red, pink, dark blue, purple, brown
>  [image: Ripple 4]
>  Light green 4: If the four was in the bottom cell of this region, there would be no place for the four in the bottom-left region.
>  Dark blue 1: The only number that can go there.

5:

> Order of solving: light blue, light green, orange, red, pink, dark blue, purple, brown, black, grey, yellow
>  [image: Ripple 5]
>  Light blue 3: if the 3 was on the right cell of the region, the bottom-right region couldn't have a 3.
>  Light green 4: If a 1 or a 2 was here, we wouldn't be able to place both a 1 and 2 in the central region bordering the bottom.
>  Orange 3: If the three was in the centre of the + region, we would have this:
>  [image: Ripple 5 Orange 3]
>  and nothing could go in the top of the + region.
>  Red 2 and 4: Similar, if these were the other way around, we wouldn't be able to place anything in the top of the + region.