# A spiral Ripple Effect puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

I'd say the rules to a ripple effect puzzle are best explained [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47718/question-16-ripple-effect).

---

Anyways, I was making a bunch of Ripple Effects and decided to do a big one which didn't work out as I'd hoped, in that I needed some numbers to force a unique solution. But don't worry. Here it is:

[image]

(Click on the picture or [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPBY3.png) for the full size picture)

<sub>Hint helpfulness level 0</sub>

> I *did* make the puzzle from the center of the spiral

<sub>Hint helpfulness level -1</sub>

> You might as well give up if you need so many hints

Comment: I was just about to do something productive! >:|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Note: if you scroll down, there will be spoilers, so be warned

<sup>The reason I have posted this answer is since JonMark Pery hasn't corrected their solution in over a week and it doesn't have workings, which I still believe are necessary</sup>

My answer is:

> [image: Answer]

## Steps (warning again - unspoilered!)

Notes: Sorry to the colourblind, but colours proceed in rainbow order, then brown, then get greyed out in the next image - if a step seems hard to follow, make sure you do everything else up to that point, then feel free to ask me - also, I definitely haven't made the solve part optimal, but a new area of work tends to come at the start of a new image - click on the images for better resolution.

[image: A] [image: B] [image: C] [image: D] [image: E] [image: F] [image: G] [image: H] [image: I] [image: J]

Comment: Congratulations! I'd started on one (a bit ambitious as my very first puzzle of this type), and with a lot more "workings" (using Excel and, taking screenshots from time to time). I'd used a technique where every box was marked with what numbers it could be (or if all but one, the number it couldn't be with a - in front of it) and a few other codes. Unfortunately found that I was about to put two "2"s in the same box following the latest deduction, and found I would have needed to unwind nearly half of the puzzle to get back to the error, and lost interest after that. Well done for finishing!

Comment: @Steve Thanks! Maybe, one day, you can start afresh, and get the satisfaction of solving the puzzle for yourself too.

Answer (score 7):

Took me all day! (I've got 40+ images of stage-by-stage grids if anyone wants to check it!)

> [image: big ripple effect solution]

Comment: I think since this is a grid-**deduction** puzzle, step-by-step images are in order

Comment: On the contrary, that really will take too long, and it is wrong to make Jon obligated to spend more time on this answer.  This should be just fine, and at most, maybe some "progress pictures".

Comment: There's a minor inaccuracy in the bottom left, 3 up and 3 across - the 6s fail. Apart from that (and the small ripples it causes) the rest seems fine!